# Stop a timer running when user hits back button (UINavigationController)

Tags: ios

I'm using UINavigationController. How do I stop (call the invalidate method) on my timer when the user hits the back button.

Comment: What Have You Tried? http://infinite-josiah.blogspot.com/2012/12/prove-that-you-have-tried.html

Comment: What about viewWillDisappear?

Comment: Good point Ace Legend, I wasn't sure how to tackle this issue, I spent some time researching on stack overflow and in the docs, but as a newbie iOS developer I didn't get very far. Next time I'll make sure to outline what I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you can use `viewWillDisappear` method to detect indirectly when back is pressed and invalidate your timer

Comment: This worked as well, seem like the simpler solution that creating a custom button.

Comment: Indeed. I just wish I would have posted my comment sooner. :)

Answer (score 0):

//Put this viewDidLoad and make sure you have a back.png that mimics back button

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem; 

- (void)backPressed:(id)sender {
     [yourTimer invalidate];
  }
```

If the timer is running in another class use NSNotificationCenter to post a notification in backPressed Method

See NSNotification Center example here [NSNotification Tutorial](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/dead-simple-nsnotification-example-iphone/)

Comment: Thanks this worked. I assume this approach (creating a custom back button) mean I can't avail of the auto-generated back buttons by UINavigationController?